# Consolidação de tabelas em MSAccess e VBA

Tags: microsoft-access, vba

Tenho a seguinte base de dados em access:

```
mov_atm
n_mov conta  data          valor         mov_sc
100   200    1/8/2014      500           n_mov   conta   data        valor
101   900    5/8/2014      800           200     900     5/8/2014    800 
102   100    1/8/2014      500           109     100     1/8/2014    500
103   100    1/8/2014      500
```

Com o resultado pretendo obter o seguinte:

```
n_mov conta  data          valor         mov_sc
                                         n_mov   conta   data        valor
101   900    1/8/2014      800           102     900     5/8/2014    800 
102   100    5/8/2014      900           101     100     1/8/2014    500
```

Note que o numero de registros que existem na tabela `mov_atm` não é o mesmo com o da tabela `mov_sc` certo?
O que pretendo é  que o `n_mov` da `tabela mov_sc` deve herdar o `n_mov` da tabela `mov_atm` e que não  apareçam dados repetidos quero que fique  como mostra no resultado .

Como posso fazer para ter esse resultado usando `Access.vba`?

Comment: Você poderia usar o {edit]ar e formatar melhor sua pergunta. Está difícil entender desta forma.

Comment: Adicione para mim como você deseja a saida que te ajudo para montar o SQL. Está meio confuso. E outra coisa, qual a ligação entre as tabela? conta?

Comment: De quais campos você realmente precisa no resultado?

Comment: O resultado que você adicionou em sua pergunta não faz sentido. Os campos conta e data não são iguais, apesar de na consulta isto estar indicado. É possível que você tenha adicionado um outro resultado?

Comment: nao sei se agora fui claro mas se nao fui peso p darem um toque mas em suma e isso que pretendo fazer.abs aguardo.de mocambique

Comment: Oi, Alex de Moçambique, não sei se você notou, mas o pessoal aqui [anda tendo bastante trabalho pra melhorar seus posts](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/16312/revisions). Por favor, aproveite sua participação aqui pra melhorar sua redação: acentos, pontos, maiúsculas, ortografia, formatação... Isso vai lhe ser útil na vida profissional também. Boa sorte!

Comment: valeu mano obrigado pela dica.

Comment: quem tiver uma dica para o problema em questão agradeço

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema ocorre devido aos códigos `n_mov_sc` e `n_mov_atm` não serem iguais no resultado.

Para realizar o que você quer, pode-se criar uma tabela temporária, sem esses código, da seguinte forma:

```
CREATE TABLE mv_sc_atm
(conta INT,
 data  DATE,
 valor INT);
```

Após criada a tabela, inserimos os dados:

```
INSERT INTO mv_sc_atm SELECT mov_sc.conta, mov_sc.data, mov_sc.valor 
                      FROM   mov_sc, mov_atm WHERE mov_sc.conta = mov_atm.conta AND 
                             mov_sc.data = mov_atm.data
```

Após isso, executamos a consulta:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM mv_sc_atm;
```

No final, destrua a tabela usando o seguinte comando:

```
DROP TABLE mv_sc_atm
```

Segue o link para o SQL Fiddle que utilizei para recriar seu cenário:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2717f/2/0

Comment: nao tem como criar uma função capaz de fazer isso usando access.vba ou vb6?